# sequelize.js - set column value on create

Tags: javascript, database, sequelize.js

What I'm trying to do here is automatically set a column value when the entry gets created.

So let's say that if I were to have a `Posts` table which has the columns:

`:id     :integer     :primary
:title  :string
:post   :text
:slug   :string      :unique`

and I create a new entry of this with sequelize by calling `Model.Posts.create` then I want the slug column to be automatically set to a value (the title slugified) when it gets created without having to do anything.

How would I have this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a beforeCreate hook:

```
sequelize.define('post', attributes, {
    hooks: {
        beforeCreate: function (instance) {
            instance.set('slug', slugify(instance.get('title'));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: is there a way to set not existing column? (create a new one in a hook)